# c# Compact Framework Not Supported Exception on Math.Sinh

Tags: c#, math, compact-framework

I'm devolping on **Compact Framework 2.0 SP1** and when I try to use **Math.Sinh** it throws me a *Not Supported Exception*

If I can't use this function, is there any other alternative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sinh(x) = (e^x - e^-x) / 2
```

[see wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_trigonometric_function)

So you should be able to write your own function !

Comment: +1 yeah, I had forgotten the formula. No need to use Taylor series.

Answer (score 2):

We use [OpenNETCF](http://www.opennetcf.com/FreeSoftware/tabid/84/Default.aspx) to gain access to a lot of APIs that the Compact Framework just doesn't support.  The Math package is just one of the them.  Indeed, OpenNETCF does support the Sinh function.

```
OpenNETCF.Math2.Sinh(angle: double)
```

If you do a lot of work with the Compact Framework, the [OpenNETCF Smart Device Framework](http://www.opennetcf.com/Default.aspx?tabid=91) can be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the PInvoke signatures of Math.Sin for example, I suspect Sinh would be there on the mobile device, but just not mapped/imported into the CF to save a byte or 2.

Comment: They are not P/Invoked. They are marked as InternalCall (implemented in the CLR itself)